# error message with AsyncValidator is not visible

Tags: angularjs

The required directive shows the red error message that works!
The uniqueschoolclassnumberValidator directive shows NOT the red error message!

From the server I always return exists => true, but I also tried it with false.

What do I wrong? The custom directive is triggered for sure!

**Directive**

```
 'use strict';
angular.module('TGB').directive('uniqueschoolclassnumberValidator', function (schoolclassCodeService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.unique = function (schoolclass) {
                var schoolclassNumber = "0a";
                var schoolyearId = 1;
                return schoolclassCodeService.exists(schoolyearId, schoolclassNumber);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

**Service**

```
this.exists = function (schoolyearId, schoolclassNumber) {

      var path = 'api/schoolyears/' + schoolyearId + '/schoolclasses/' + schoolclassNumber;
      return $http.get(path).then(function (response) {
          if (response.data == true) {
              $q.reject("schoolclass number has already been taken");
          }
          else {
              return $q.resolve();
          }
      });
  };
```

**Html**

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" unique-schoolclasnumber-Validator name="myInput" 
               ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 300, 'blur': 0} }"
               ng-model="schoolclassNumber" class="form-control" 
               required placeholder="Enter schoolclass">
    </div>
    <div ng-messages="myForm.myInput.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="required">You did not enter anything.</div>
        <div ng-message="unique">That schoolclass number already exists.</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service's exists method there should be return keyword before $q.reject:

```
if (response.data == true) {
     return $q.reject("schoolclass number has already been taken");
}
else {
     return $q.resolve();
}
```

Directive should be named `uniqueSchoolclassnumberValidator` instead of `uniqueschoolclassnumberValidator` (AngularJS change dash-delimited format to camelCase).

There is also a misspell in html code, in word "class". It should be `unique-schoolclassnumber-Validator` instead of `unique-schoolclasnumber-Validator`.

Comment: The misspell comes from a copy/paste error I did here on SO. But damn yes the return was missing and I have just not seen it! Now it works!